# Zend Framework 1 get param from route

Tags: php, zend-framework, model-view-controller, zend-view

I have a basic layout.phtml script that I use on every page. Now I would like to add an active class to the page loaded. So I would like to do like this:

```
class=" if route ends with = ''? active : not-active "
```

How can I do this in a ZF view?

I need this because I have a page with 4 links to the same action but different parameters and I want to see wich one is selected..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller hit:

```
$this->view->assign('myParam', $this->getRequest()->getParam('yourParam', ''));
```

In the view put:

```
<?php echo ($this->myParam != '') ? 'active' : 'non-active'; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

So the class you would like to add is in layout but you want to send the content form the particular embedded view script

Placeholders were meant for this purpose 
http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.placeholder

So in layout you would do something like for instance

```
<body class="<?php echo $this->placeholder('bodyClasses') ?>">
```

then in your viewscript you can do for example

```
$this->placeholder('bodyClasses')
    ->set('nameofpage');
```